# Active classes no longer being assigned (PHP) after Joomla 3.3.0 Migration / PHP 5.4.29 Update

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, migration, joomla3.0

I just migrated to Joomla! 3.3.1, and my active menu classes are no longer working:

```
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" <?php if($ItemId == '1'){echo 'class="active"';}?>><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&Itemid=2" <?php if($ItemId == '2'){echo 'class="active"';}?>><span>About The Practice</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3&Itemid=3" <?php if($ItemId == '3'){echo 'class="active"';}?>><span>Our Doctors & Providers</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

I also had to update the site to PHP version 5.4.29, I'm not sure what has the bigger influence here. As mentioned, before the migration the menu classes were being assigned as desired. Now, no menu classes are being assigned at all. I have already had to make some tweaks to account for conflicts that the migration caused (i.e. changing "$"s to "jQuery"s). I'm pretty novice with PHP.

The $ItemId is set as follows:

```
$ItemId = isset($_GET['Itemid'])?$_GET['Itemid']:'';
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery 1.2.6? Joomla gets shipped with more or less the latest version of jQuery so why don't you use that? Can you also show the code you're using to define the `$ItemId` variable?

Comment: Have you got PHP errors turned on? Is there any clues in the PHP Error log?

Comment: I've never used the error reporting before so I just looked it up. I changed Error Reporting in the Joomla! Administrator panel to "Development", then I went and looked at the Console in Firefox and an unrelated error came up (I fixed it). Now it's blank? As implied, I'm not sure if I'm checking this correctly...

Comment: Migrated from what version?

Comment: I migrated step-by-step all the way from 1.5. However, everything was still perfect at 2.5.20. So this problem only occurred in the migration phase between 2.5.20 to 3.3.0.

Comment: Why aren't you just using the default Joomla menu module? That highlights active items out-the-box...

Comment: from 2.5 to 3.x the core switched to bootstrap and also started shipping its own jquery, so unfortunately that means a fair amount of tuning of your template.